Locating Babylonian birth-omen tablets
It seems the Babylonian divinatory tablets is in the public domain, however, I'm quite unable to find English translations for it.
https://ancientworldonline.blogspot.com/2013/12/cuneiform-texts-from-babylonian-tablets.html
I realize these come to us primarily in fragments with a rather byzantine classification system, which I'm guessing is the reason they are so hard to track down for non-experts. And the divinatory tablets cover a wide variety of different omens (from astronomical to all kinds of other ones). To narrow the scope of the question, I'm principally interested in the so-called "birth omen" tablets.
During my search, I found (and read) a vintage book that came up in the search results: Babylonian-assyrian Birth-omens and Their Cultural Significance. It contains many of the birth omens in the form of direct translation, and was helpful; its notes citations also helped me zero in on the specific tablets:
Layard (a British Indiana Jones who discovered Nineveh and whose biography "Winged Bull" I'd recommend) gave us his Cuneiform Texts from Babylon. Some sections feature birth omens:

Part XXVII
Part XXVIII

But again, it's in cuneiform, not helpful for non-specialists.
Question
Is there a centralized English language translation of the birth omen tablets (Layard's), or even better, a more up to date database in English that includes all birth omen tablets, whether discovered in Layard's day or more recently (in English of course)?
